# Iterating csv files with json file information

Tags: python

I have a collection of json and csv files, all with the same names - just different extensions. I am trying to:

i) Iterate the extraction of information from the json file, to populate the appropriate csv file.

ii) Save the newly created dataframe as a new .csv file

My code below only loops for one file. How can I get it to loop through all the .csv and .json files in the current working directory?

```
import pandas as pd
import glob2
import json as jamison


#glob returns a list of files with csv & .json file extensions 
csv_filenames = glob2.glob("*.csv")
csv_files = len(csv_filenames)

json_filenames = glob2.glob("*.json")
json_files = len(json_filenames)


#Json function to determine the variables within the file:
def json_variables(json_full_file, csv_file_iteration):

    json_data=open(json_full_file).read()

    data = jamison.loads(json_data) # json.load() is for loading a file. json.loads() works with strings.

    #define the variables from the json file
    username = data["target_username"]
    analysis_start_date = data["options"]["start"]
    analysis_end_date = data["options"]["end"]

    #Open the csv in pandas - then write the new columns (username, start, end)
    csv_df=pd.read_csv(csv_file_iteration, index_col=None, encoding='utf-8') #filename (sample.csv) defined in the function

    #Add columns 'username, analysis start date, analysis end date, analysis days' to csv (referencing json file)
    csv_df['username'] = username #defined in the function bracket
    csv_df['analysis_start_date'] = analysis_start_date #defined in the function bracket
    csv_df['analysis_end_date'] = analysis_end_date #defined in the function bracket

    #Export final dataframe to individual .csv files:
    csv_df.to_csv(username + '.csv', index=False, header=True)

    print("Complete: %s\n" % (csv))    



#Compare the json filename with the csv filename

for json_full, csv in zip(json_filenames, csv_filenames):
    json_variables(json_full, csv)
        #print("Complete: %s\n" % (csv))

        #Change the csv filename      

print("Iteration complete.")
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to answer without a look at the directory from which you are extracting your filenames.One possible reason could be the number of csv files could be less than or equal to the number of json files. If that is the case your zip function wont work as expected. the length of the lists should be equal, else the elements in the longer list is truncated. Could that be the case?

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [1,2]
for i in zip(a,b):
    print(i)
#(1, 1)
#(2, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

My mistake, I had a variable name 'username', but was referring to it as 'user_name' in one instance.